# Is there an apply type function in R to generate samples of different sizes from a vector?

Tags: r

Let's say that I have two vectors `x=c(1:10)`, `y=c(20:30)` and two more larger length vectors let's say
`n1=c(100:200)`, `n2=c(200:300)`.

I want to get samples (with replacement of course) from `x` of sizes that `n1` depicts and from `y` that `n2` depicts, i.e. first 100 and store their sum, then 101 and store their sum etc until 200 and then the samy for variable `y`. Is there any idea of how to avoid the for loop to do that?

I want to end up with a matrix that has in the first column the sums of the samples of `x` and the second column the sums of the samples of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with a loop here... or a loop hidden in an `sapply`:

```
x_n1_sums = sapply(n1, function(z) sum(sample(x, size = z, replace = TRUE)))
y_n2_sums = sapply(n2, function(z) sum(sample(y, size = z, replace = TRUE)))
```

Note that these are just slightly condensed ways of writing out a loop. You could just as well do:

```
x_n1_sums = integer(length(n1))
for(i in seq_along(n1)) {
  x_n1_sums[i] = sum(sample(x, size = n1[i], replace = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: can these two commands you wrote x_n1_sums and y_n2_sums be summarized to one command, because I have to do this almost 300 times?

Comment: I mean, you can write a function that takes arguments, `foo = function(n, vec) {sapply(n, function(z) sum(sample(vec, size = z, replace = TRUE)))}` and then call `foo(n1, x)`, `foo(n1, y)`. But since `n1 != n2` and `x != y`, it seems pointless to put those calculations together. If you have a lot of variables hopefully you are using a data structure like a `data.frame` [or a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) rather than sequentially named variables... If your variables are in a data structure looping over them is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could put Gregor's `sapply` into a `Map` call and use `mget` to grab your ~300 variable pairs from your workspace.

#### Solution 1

```
set.seed(42)
res <- Map(function(n, x) sapply(n, function(x, z) sum(sample(x, size=x, replace=TRUE)), x), 
           mget(paste0("n", 1:3)), mget(paste0("x", 1:3)))
```

**Result**

```
res
# $n1
#  [1]  4978  5092  5283  5388  5420  5738  5573  5919  5722  6529  6316
# [12]  6139  6449  6397  6468  6509  6363  7292  7265  7402  7021  6942
# [23]  7692  7582  7822  7291  8556  8094  7981  8754  9135  8475  8248
# [34]  9393  9019  9526  9644  9259  8970 10132  9607  9387 10784  9289
# [45] 10754 10587 11221 11124 10608 10179 11316 11518 11484 11543 12143
# [56] 12989 12735 12596 12967 10797 11470 12179 13665 12289 14454 13615
# [67] 15095 13114 14614 15732 14359 13981 13165 16073 15491 13936 15536
# [78] 15344 14836 17143 16005 16773 16240 16941 15804 17564 17379 17322
# [89] 17345 19950 17827 18920 18596 16919 17882 18726 18110 19984 19318
# [100] 19663 20269
# 
# $n2
#  [1] 20295 21295 20518 19210 21409 22386 21364 20367 19515 23105 23371
# [12] 23842 23468 23933 22296 22832 22672 25237 25101 23490 23267 25867
# [23] 24151 24247 25679 24107 25360 24675 25567 25607 27670 26662 28478
# [34] 28203 26617 28843 26182 27908 28560 27190 29840 31566 30309 28351
# [45] 28916 30026 29089 31159 30579 31835 32682 31770 32310 32142 31964
# [56] 31421 31044 32155 32557 33202 34205 34566 34153 33589 31831 33486
# [67] 37466 34722 36257 34910 35638 37128 35913 36201 40031 37720 38232
# [78] 38718 39940 37769 36714 41539 41617 37948 41666 42407 40008 40601
# [89] 43563 41941 42636 43073 39286 43103 43510 44785 43444 43998 45678
# [100] 46244 47021
# 
# $n3
#  [1] 46006 47640 45236 45229 46936 44924 45400 49306 48429 48752 46101
# [12] 47612 52132 47411 46958 46082 50105 51873 49299 46963 52396 53336
# [23] 50490 53146 52912 56005 51678 52715 52141 56446 56304 55270 56233
# [34] 56514 58445 51637 55880 57316 57663 59554 54236 54819 61929 58387
# [45] 56888 58575 58663 59174 62947 65705 59852 62723 62621 58702 60114
# [56] 63817 61939 62426 63192 62476 65098 65568 67466 70020 64776 65646
# [67] 68086 69753 68597 70598 74347 69225 68329 75894 69546 71321 69488
# [78] 74288 71575 69625 69752 67965 71759 74306 74373 75003 73970 71771
# [89] 73239 75570 75231 78031 78555 78968 76116 76290 79374 79989 77838
# [100] 79819 81109
```

#### Solution 2

Or in the matrix case (see comment).

```
set.seed(42)
res <- mapply(function(n, x) sapply(n, function(x, z) sum(sample(x, size=x, replace=TRUE)), x), 
           as.data.frame(N), as.data.frame(X))
```

**Result**

```
res
# n1    n2    n3
# [1,]  4557 21390 46224
# [2,]  4730 20593 45036
# [3,]  5304 20686 45713
# [4,]  5181 20838 48072
# [5,]  5782 19631 48738
# [6,]  5027 22297 47345
# [7,]  5764 21091 47339
# [8,]  5600 21230 45641
# [9,]  5716 21020 48194
# [10,]  6255 21748 47226
# [11,]  6281 23919 50694
# [12,]  6368 20777 49840
# [13,]  6067 23884 47946
# [14,]  6710 21705 51508
# [15,]  6846 23811 52632
# [16,]  6950 23932 46732
# [17,]  6586 24824 50691
# [18,]  6980 22466 50747
# [19,]  6718 25260 52010
# [20,]  6866 23362 52200
# [21,]  7842 25005 49955
# [22,]  7095 24620 53393
# [23,]  7024 25055 52922
# [24,]  7750 24493 50034
# [25,]  8019 26124 50297
# [26,]  7981 27113 53247
# [27,]  8103 25540 51848
# [28,]  8243 26843 51241
# [29,]  8302 25642 53940
# [30,]  8632 26775 55112
# [31,]  8198 26909 54559
# [32,]  9259 28335 54736
# [33,]  9045 26858 56934
# [34,]  8687 26882 55029
# [35,]  9023 28942 59308
# [36,]  8459 29333 56032
# [37,]  9819 28123 57040
# [38,]  8929 26026 57613
# [39,]  9357 29223 52860
# [40,] 11236 30784 59318
# [41,]  9697 27775 59480
# [42,]  9961 30569 59968
# [43,]  9281 31688 56250
# [44,] 10422 30423 58201
# [45,] 10135 28990 59129
# [46,] 10941 29856 57587
# [47,] 11777 31513 58765
# [48,] 11028 32374 55899
# [49,] 11023 32168 62379
# [50,] 10413 30418 59354
# [51,] 11867 33008 58512
# [52,] 11000 31445 62448
# [53,] 11757 33587 61652
# [54,] 11934 33203 59858
# [55,] 12179 32286 62068
# [56,] 12195 31595 67006
# [57,] 12023 33316 63311
# [58,] 13444 32450 62873
# [59,] 12739 31884 63376
# [60,] 12699 35333 63013
# [61,] 12239 32621 66080
# [62,] 13751 33761 63407
# [63,] 13294 34145 67968
# [64,] 13674 35789 66286
# [65,] 15203 35859 66017
# [66,] 13367 36746 65226
# [67,] 13804 35473 68551
# [68,] 14338 36512 66777
# [69,] 13511 38545 68397
# [70,] 13519 34987 64400
# [71,] 13768 33394 66711
# [72,] 14611 36195 66209
# [73,] 14667 35841 64381
# [74,] 14900 36682 68143
# [75,] 16008 38334 68719
# [76,] 15006 37555 71335
# [77,] 15403 35518 71890
# [78,] 16159 38154 72890
# [79,] 16971 40389 74732
# [80,] 15804 39832 71549
# [81,] 16988 41786 73404
# [82,] 16489 39934 70910
# [83,] 17238 40637 69625
# [84,] 15947 40782 74477
# [85,] 16265 40399 76900
# [86,] 17685 41937 76328
# [87,] 17165 43287 78224
# [88,] 18084 38838 71176
# [89,] 16233 43162 74248
# [90,] 16713 43828 78293
# [91,] 18397 41304 78578
# [92,] 18574 42549 76102
# [93,] 18425 45310 73165
# [94,] 17854 43327 79458
# [95,] 19946 43807 78581
# [96,] 17291 44097 74152
# [97,] 19718 45748 78085
# [98,] 19708 47821 79974
# [99,] 19734 44316 81048
# [100,] 19268 45343 79915
# [101,] 21176 43944 85171
```

Note that I've also used `mapply` here instead of `Map` which gives back a matrix. To get a list instead just use `Map` as above. If your matrices are transposed, do e.g. `as.data.frame(t(N))`.

---

*Data:*

```
## vectors solution 1
n1=c(100:200)
n2=c(200:300)
n3=c(300:400)
x1=c(1:10)
x2=c(21:30)
x3=c(31:40)

## matrices solution 2
N <- cbind(n1, n2, n3)
X <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: I have a matrix and not individual vectors, so this will not work in my case. I just wrote it like that to simplify the problem. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @manos92 That's what one would call "oversimplified" :) Aha, and how would your matrix look like?

Comment: The x's are contained in a matrix 1e4x360 and the n's are 1e5x360

Comment: @manos92 Please check update of my answer.